# SQL Server on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux

While running "sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup" to configure sql server i keep getting the error "sudo: Please use single character options". I am running the above command as root user.

Comment: I'm not much of a Linux guru but if you're already logged in as root do you need the sudo command? It might be worth trying without it.

Comment: Tried without sudo as well, no luck